# hibernate: exception when saving an entity without a foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create an entity in the database, without a foreign key, and update the foreign key at a later stage.

```
@Entity
public class Business {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int businessId;

    @Column
    private String businessName;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="billTypeId", nullable=true)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private BillType billType;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The billType attribute has a null value and I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn:54) 
Column 'billTypeId' cannot be null
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:152)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:118)
```

How can I persist the business Object and have a zero value in the billTypeId field, when the billType member is null

Comment: Your code contradicts with the constraints enforced by the database. I would remove the NotFound annotation (which is a hack to deal with inconsistent databases), and I would simply set the bill type before saving the entity.

Comment: There are no constraints enforced by the database. 
I know I can set the billType and make it work. However I need to save the Business object without a BillType first, and set it in a later stage. My question is how?

Comment: That's not what the exception says: `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. You'd almost think a constraint were violated.

Comment: There are, otherwise the database wouldn't throw an exception saying "Column 'billTypeId' cannot be null". That's the sign of a not null constraint existing on the column. Again, you're trying to solve the problem the wrong way: the database says: "a billlType may never, ever be null". And you're trying to insert a row without a billType.

Comment: I thought you were referring to a foreign key constraint, which does not exist.
I am trying to put zero in this field without creating a mock BillType object.
In the database the field billTypeId has a default value of zero, so I don't see why it can't have its default value.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default specifies that a value will only have default value if it is not specified. I suspect when you check the insert statement for your entity, you will find that the foreign key is specified with value null.

Comment: Yes it is. How can I (if possible) make hibernate use an insert without the field when the value is null?

Comment: Could you post your persist code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would suggest to reconsider the approach and allow null values on `billTypeId` column in database as this is standard behavior. Also `0` value will be considered a referenced `ID` by any foreign key constraint you may specify in the future.

Still if you want to try different approach

One option is to change the flush mode from `AUTO` (default) to `COMMIT` or `MANUAL` and build full entity tree before actually flushing anything to database. (`AUTO` checks for session changes before each `SELECT` and flushes the changes to database if there are any. This ensures that you are reading the latest data, but also kills the performance.)

Additionally Hibernate provides

- `@DynamicInsert` annotation that will advice Hibernate to generate `INSERT` statement only for not null column values ([doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-dynamicinsert))
- `@DynamicUpdate` annotation that will advice Hibernate to generate `UPDATE` statement only for not columns which values have changed ([doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-dynamicupdate))

I recommend to use this kind of approach with extreme care.

Alternatively you can specify `insertable` and `updatable` attibutes of `@JoinColumn` annotation ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html)). If you use case is to insert record without link and update it on later modifications then `insertable=false` should work for you.

Comment: Please vote up or accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but it doesn't count my vote yet, since I'm a noob in this site.